# Rebuilding git master from the local repos

Tags: git

I have one git remote master and two local git repos that pull from and push to that master; they are the only repos using that master. The three repos run on separate machines.

The VM for the master got corrupted and trashed my remote master. However, I still have the two local repos, so I have all the data and all the branches that I actually care about.

What's the easiest way to rebuild a master that is the union of the two local repos and use that as my remote master henceforth?

Comment: Local repositories contain the full history, so ideally, your local repositories should both be identical to the remote repository. As such, simply pushing the branches using `git push` should work fine.

Comment: OK, so I use git init for an empty repo on the remote, and then run git push from the locals to populate the master?

Comment: Yeah, you could delete the existing one, then initialize a new one (using `git init --bare`) and then push from the local repositories to set it up again.

Comment: Looks like it takes a bit more than that; the `git push` command fails with the inability to update a check-out branch.

Comment: Your remote repository should be a *bare* repository (one without a working directory), so you can interact with it freely.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the process that poke explained to me.

1. On the remote machine, create a bare repository. `git init --bare DIR` (Notice that if you were *not* pulling from a bare repository previously, your remotes will be looking for a `.git` directory, but a bare repository does not have a `.git` subdirectory automatically, so you either have to be explicit, i.e. `DIR/.git`, or you need to edit the remote in the `.git/config` file.)
2. From the local repos, rebase your master to the latest version, e.g. `git checkout master && git rebase work` then push that out to the remote `git push origin`.

You may get a scary-looking warning like so

```
warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value has changed in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the traditional behavior, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple

When push.default is set to 'matching', git will push local branches
to the remote branches that already exist with the same name.

...
```

The message had no impact on my situation.